# Como eu crio um intervalo de tempo na execução de um for?

Tags: javascript, for, setinterval, settimeout

Como eu crio  um intervalo de 1 segundo na execução do `for` ou da `function`?

```
JavaScript:

function Linha1() {
            for (var i1 = 0; i1 <= 3; i1++, Linha1.setInterval(1000)) {
                if (notas1[0][i1] == 1) {
                    C_Teclado.play();
                } else if (notas1[i1][0] == 2) {
                    CS_Teclado.play();
                } else if (notas1[i1][0] == 3) {
                    D_Teclado.play();
                } else if (notas1[i1][0] == 4) {
                    _Teclado.play();
                } else if (notas1[i1][0] == 5) {
                    E_Teclado.play();
                } else {
                    SomVazio.play();
                }

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Para "atrasar" a execução de algo, basta envolver o que você quer atrasar com o setTimeout e determinar o tempo em milissegundos. Como no exemplo:

```
setTimeout(function Linha1() {
                for (var i1 = 0; i1 <= 3; i1++, Linha1.setInterval(1000)) {
                    if (notas1[0][i1] == 1) {
                        C_Teclado.play();
                    } else if (notas1[i1][0] == 2) {
                        CS_Teclado.play();
                    } else if (notas1[i1][0] == 3) {
                        D_Teclado.play();
                    } else if (notas1[i1][0] == 4) {
                        _Teclado.play();
                    } else if (notas1[i1][0] == 5) {
                        E_Teclado.play();
                    } else {
                        SomVazio.play();
                    }

                }
            }, 1000
          )
```

Comment: O problema é que eu gostaria de 'atrasar' o intervalo entre as execuções do for e não a execução da function

Answer (score -1):

Você pode substituir o seu for por um setInterval se o intervalo for ser sempre do mesmo tamanho, o seu código ficaria:

```
setTimeout(function Linha1() {
    let i = 0

    let interval = setInterval(function () {
        if (i > 3) return clearInterval(interval)

        if (notas1[0][i1] == 1) {
            C_Teclado.play();
        } else if (notas1[i1][0] == 2) {
            CS_Teclado.play();
        } else if (notas1[i1][0] == 3) {
            D_Teclado.play();
        } else if (notas1[i1][0] == 4) {
            _Teclado.play();
        } else if (notas1[i1][0] == 5) {
            E_Teclado.play();
        } else {
            SomVazio.play();
        }

        i++
    }, 1000)
}, 1000)
```